# How display picture in a IOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, image

I'm a beginner to build an IOS app and I want to know the good practice to display user picture on my app. I searched on google if some practice or document talk about that but i found nothing... My question mark is:

> What is the common ratio to use when we want a "portrait picture" or "selfie"?

For my app I need to display a fixed ratio image and I would like authorize the user to crop the image, so do you know a library to help me to do that?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: trying to show photo in uiimageView ? camera or gallery ?

Comment: @Ryan110 in an app so in uiimageView

Answer (score 1):

this is what i'm using :

displayPhotoImageView is uiimageView photo loads on it

var newpic:Bool?

```
  func photoAction(){

        let myalert=UIAlertController(title:"",message:"choose photo  ",preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let camerAction=UIAlertAction(title:"camera",style:.default){(action) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {

                let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagepicker.delegate = self
                imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                imagepicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as! String]
                imagepicker.allowsEditing = false

                self.present(imagepicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.newpic = true
            }

        }


       // let camerRollAction=UIAlertController(title:"",message:"",preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let camerRollAction=UIAlertAction(title:"Gallery",style:.default){(action) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {

                let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagepicker.delegate = self
                imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
                imagepicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as! String]
                imagepicker.allowsEditing = false

                self.present(imagepicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.newpic = true
            }

        }

        myalert.addAction(camerAction)
        myalert.addAction(camerRollAction)

        self.present(myalert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


        let mediatype = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString


        if mediatype.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as! String) {

            let image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

            displayPhotoImageView.image = image

            let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData

           data = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

            if newpic == true {

                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(imageError), nil)
            }
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imageError(image:UIImage,didFinishSavingWithError error:NSErrorPointer,ContextInfo:UnsafeRawPointer){

        if error != nil {

            let alert=UIAlertController(title: "error ", message: " unable ", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let ok=UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .cancel, handler:nil )

            alert.addAction(ok)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }


    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

you need Privacy - Camera Usage Description and Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description permission

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this code is for select picture in the library or camera but he can't crop the image and my question is what is the ratio to use for a "selfi" picture ?